# Unable to run ClojureScript Hello World program, "Error building classpath. Error reading edn."

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to run a simple ClojureScript hello world program using instructions from [the ClojureScript QuickStart page](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start), but when I run the command `clj -M --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl` (in the hello-world project folder), I am getting this error : `Error building classpath. Error reading edn. Invalid number: 1.10.758 (/some_path_to_/deps.edn)`.

The ClojureScript code is:

```
(ns hello-world.core)

(println "Hello world!")
```

and the `deps.edn` file contains:
`{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version 1.10.758}}}`

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double-quotes around the version number.  Sample file:

```
{:deps    {
           org.clojure/clojure             {:mvn/version "1.10.2-alpha1"}
           org.clojure/clojurescript       {:mvn/version "1.10.764"}

           com.bhauman/figwheel-main       {:mvn/version "0.2.11"}
           com.bhauman/rebel-readline-cljs {:mvn/version "0.1.4"}

           re-frame                        {:mvn/version "1.0.0"}
           reagent                         {:mvn/version "0.10.0"}
           reagent-utils                   {:mvn/version "0.3.3"}

           org.clojure/spec.alpha          {:mvn/version "0.2.176"}
           prismatic/schema                {:mvn/version "1.1.12"}
           tupelo                          {:mvn/version "20.07.21"}
           }

 :paths   ["src" "test" "target" "resources"]

 :aliases {
           :ancient {:main-opts  ["-m" "deps-ancient.deps-ancient"]
                     :extra-deps {deps-ancient {:mvn/version "RELEASE"}}}
           :fig     {:main-opts ["-m" "figwheel.main"]}
           :dev     {:main-opts ["-m" "figwheel.main" "--build" "dev" "--repl"]
                     ; :extra-deps {tupelo {:local/root "/Users/r634165/tupelo/target/uberjar/tupelo-0.9.XXXXX-standalone.jar"}}
                     }
           }
 }
```

I have not used CLJS recently, but the above shows the proper form.